cgroup memory.max is overridden by docker
I've created cgroup mygroup.slice with the following script. The value of memory.max is 200M. I can see the content of memory.max is 209715200.
sudo mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/mygroup.slice
echo "200M" | sudo tee "/sys/fs/cgroup/mygroup.slice/memory.max"
echo "+memory" | sudo tee "/sys/fs/cgroup/mygroup.slice/cgroup.subtree_control"
cat "/sys/fs/cgroup/mygroup.slice/memory.max"

Then I started a docker container with cgroup-parent.
docker run -d --cgroup-parent mygroup.slice --env CONTAINER_NAME=container1 --name container1 simple/container1

After that the content of memory.max is max instead of 209715200.
How can I stop docker to override that? Thanks.
Here are details of my environment.
cgroup v2 is used.
stat -fc %T /sys/fs/cgroup/
cgroup2fs

Here is the output of docker version
docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           27.2.0
 API version:       1.47
 Go version:        go1.21.13
 Git commit:        3ab4256
 Built:             Tue Aug 27 14:15:45 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/arm64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          27.2.0
  API version:      1.47 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.13
  Git commit:       3ab5c7d
  Built:            Tue Aug 27 14:15:45 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.7.21
  GitCommit:        472731909fa34bd7bc9c087e4c27943f9835f111
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.13
  GitCommit:        v1.1.13-0-g58aa920
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0


I have asked this question in Docker Community forum and I got the answer.
The reason is cgroup driver of Docker is systemd. I should use systemd to manage cgroup.

Create a file /etc/systemd/system/mygroup.slice with the following content.

[Unit]
Description=MyGroup Slice

[Slice]
MemoryMax=200M


Reload systemd configuration

sudo systemctl daemon-reload


Start container with --cgroup-parent

docker run -d --cgroup-parent mygroup.slice --env CONTAINER_NAME=container1 --name container1 simple/container1

